# In Angular, how to do Content Projection over the list of children?

Tags: angular, children, ng-content

I have a component that should accept **arbitrary amount** of child components of known type and render them with additional wrapper in an `*ngFor`. Alternatively, can I pass and render a list of `<ng-template>`?

Container will be used like this:

```html
<app-custom-container>
   <app-custom-child name="1">...</app-custom-child>
   <app-custom-child name="2">...</app-custom-child>
   <app-custom-child name="3">...</app-custom-child>
</app-custom-container>
```

Inside container template I'd like to do something like this:

```html
template: '<div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let child of ...?">
        <app-custom-child-internal-wrapper [id]="child.id">
             <ng-content/> <!--somehow only render this specific child-->
        </app-custom-child-internal-wrapper>
    </ng-content>
</div>'
```

Can this or something similar be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is a use case for `ContentChildren` and `ngTemplateOutlet`... like so

first you need a directive to mark and get a template ref of any children you want rendered:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[childMarker]'})
export class ChildMarkerDirective {
  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) { }
}
```

then add it to the children:

```
<app-custom-container>
   <app-custom-child *childMarker name="1">...</app-custom-child>
   <app-custom-child *childMarker name="2">...</app-custom-child>
   <app-custom-child *childMarker name="3">...</app-custom-child>
</app-custom-container>
```

in your custom container controller, you need something like this to query the marker in the content:

```
@ContentChildren(ChildMarkerDirective)
children
```

then in your template, you can iterate and project:

```
<div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let child of children">
        <app-custom-child-internal-wrapper>
             <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="child.templateRef"></ng-container>
        </app-custom-child-internal-wrapper>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the idea.. but can't make it working, I got always `Error: NG0201: No provider for TemplateRef`

Comment: Needs to use the * syntax on the directive to inject template ref

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. You can use `CustomChildComponent` for template only and get a list if them with `@ContentChildren(CustomChildComponent)`

Usage:

```html
<app-custom-container>
   <app-custom-child name="1">
       <ng-template #innertemplate>
          ...
       </ng-temlate>
   </app-custom-child>
   <app-custom-child name="2">
       <ng-template #innertemplate>
            ...
       </ng-temlate>
   </app-custom-child>
</app-custom-container>
```

Child component:

```js
@Component({
  selector:    'app-custom-child',
  template: '', // template empty by design
})
export class CustomChildComponent {
    @Input() public name!: string;
   
    @ContentChild('innertemplate', { read: TemplateRef }) 
    public innerTemplateReference!: TemplateRef<any>; 
}
```

Parent component:

```js
@Component({
  selector:    'app-custom-container',
  template: '<app-some-internal-container>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let child of contentChildren">
           <app-some-internal-wrapper>
               <ng-container ngTemplateOutlet="child.innerTemplateReference">
                    
               </ng-container>
           </app-some-internal-wrapper>
       </ng-container>
  </app-some-internal-container>', 
})
export class CustomContainerComponent {   
    @ContentChildren(CustomChildComponent) 
    public contentChildren: QueryList<CustomChildComponent>;
}
```